# Objects not moving - Actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm making a game in which your are a plane trying to dodge incoming missiles. I am trying to make my baddies spawn and move from the top to the bottom of the stage. At the moment there are no errors, the baddies spawn but do not move. Please Help.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var baddies:Array = new Array();
var baddieSpeed:int = 15;
var timer: Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addBaddie);
timer.start();

//deg2rad = Math.PI/180;
//rad2deg = 180/Math.PI;

plane.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, fl_SetKeyPressed_2);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2);



function fl_MoveInDirectionOfKey_2(event:Event)
{
    if (upPressed)
    {
        plane.y -= 8;
    }
    if (downPressed)
    {
        plane.y += 8;
    }
    if (leftPressed)
    {
        plane.x -= 8;
    }
    if (rightPressed)
    {
        plane.x += 8;
    }
}

function fl_SetKeyPressed_2(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = true;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function fl_UnsetKeyPressed_2(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            upPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            downPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            leftPressed = false;
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            rightPressed = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addBaddie);
timer.start();
function addBaddie(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    var baddie:Baddie = new Baddie();
    baddie.x = - baddie.width
    baddie.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    baddie.angle = getAngle(baddie.x, baddie.y, target.x, target.y);
    baddie.rotation = getAngle(baddie.x, baddie.y, target.x, target.y);
    baddie.speed = baddieSpeed
    addChild(baddie);
    baddies.push(baddie);
    }


var counter:int = 0;
function moveBaddies():void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < baddies.length; i++) {
        var dx = Math.cos(deg2rad(baddies[i].angle)) * baddies[i].speed;
        var dy = Math.sin(deg2rad(baddies[i].angle)) * baddies[i].speed;
        baddies[i].x += dx;
        baddies[i].y += dy;
    }
}


function deg2rad(deg:Number):Number {
    return deg * (Math.PI/180);
}

function rad2deg(rad:Number):Number {
    return rad * (180 / Math.PI);
}



function getAngle(x1:Number, y1:Number, x2:Number, y2:Number):Number {
    var radians:Number = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
    return rad2deg(radians);
}
```

Comment: where are you calling function moveBaddies()?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling this twice:

`timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, addBaddie);`

I suggest you create a timer dedicated to moving the enemies:

```
var baddieMover:Timer = new Timer(40);
baddieMover.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveBaddies);
baddieMover.start();
var counter:int = 0;
function moveBaddies(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < baddies.length; i++) {
        var dx = Math.cos(deg2rad(baddies[i].angle)) * baddies[i].speed;
        var dy = Math.sin(deg2rad(baddies[i].angle)) * baddies[i].speed;
        baddies[i].x += dx;
        baddies[i].y += dy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have forgotten to call the `Movebaddies` function. As EgoAnt said - to keep it clean and all, I'd suggest you'll make a new Listener for that function.

Comment: When i added the listener:
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBaddies);

I now receive the error:
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on GameNew2_fla::MainTimeline/moveBaddies(). Expected 0, got 1.

Comment: functiom movebaddies(e:Event)